# NextJs - template issue

Tags: nextjs

I am trying to setup Sitecore Containers template for Next.js using this guide from the official [docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/20/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html). Everything works fine, no errors under installation or deployment jss app to Sitecore.

On my home page I receive only "404 page not found".

[image: Home page not found]

I checked the logs from rendering image on HTTP request and it works like a clock, even sends a JSON response with a normal page (see logs below).

```
Sitecore.LayoutService.Client.RequestHandlers.HttpLayoutRequestHandler[0]
      Layout Service Response JSON : {"sitecore":{"context":{"pageEditing":false,"site":{"name":"siteheadasp"},"pageState":"normal","language":"en","itemPath":"/"},"route":{"name":"home","displayName":"home","fields":{"pageTitle":{"value":"Welcome to Sitecore JSS - siteheadasp"}},"databaseName":"web","deviceId":"fe5d7fdf-89c0-4d99-9aa3-b5fbd009c9f3","itemId":"ca3d5cc0-f313-5d94-bcf3-eccb6ade5067","itemLanguage":"en","itemVersion":1,"layoutId":"be7ae432-5a8a-59dd-9874-62218b1621a8","templateId":"89829df8-93ee-56be-b57a-8f9efa6ba0a6","templateName":"App Route","placeholders":{"jss-main":[{"uid":"2c4a53cc-9da8-5f51-9d79-6ee2fc671b2d","componentName":"ContentBlock","dataSource":"{178A024B-6A35-5279-A4F1-328EEBFB6A19}","params":{},"fields":{"content":{"value":"<p>Thanks for using JSS!! Here are some resources to get you started:</p>\r\n\r\n<h3><a href=\"https://jss.sitecore.com\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\">Documentation</a></h3>\r\n<p>The official JSS documentation can help you with any JSS task from getting started to advanced techniques.</p>\r\n\r\n<h3><a href=\"/styleguide\">Styleguide</a></h3>\r\n<p>The JSS styleguide is a living example of how to use JSS, hosted right in this app.\r\nIt demonstrates most of the common patterns that JSS implementations may need to use,\r\nas well as useful architectural patterns.</p>\r\n\r\n<h3><a href=\"/graphql\">GraphQL</a></h3>\r\n<p>JSS features integration with the Sitecore GraphQL API to enable fetching non-route data from Sitecore - or from other internal backends as an API aggregator or proxy.\r\nThis route is a living example of how to use an integrate with GraphQL data in a JSS app.</p>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"alert alert-dark\">\r\n  <h4>This app is a boilerplate</h4>\r\n  <p>The JSS samples are a boilerplate, not a library. That means that any code in this app is meant for you to own and customize to your own requirements.</p>\r\n  <p>Want to change the lint settings? Do it. Want to read manifest data from a MongoDB database? Go for it. This app is yours.</p>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"alert alert-dark\">\r\n  <h4>How to start with an empty app</h4>\r\n  <p>To remove all of the default sample content (the Styleguide and GraphQL routes) and start out with an empty JSS app:</p>\r\n  <ol>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/src/components/Styleguide*</code> and <code>/src/components/GraphQL*</code></li>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/sitecore/definitions/components/Styleguide*</code>, <code>/sitecore/definitions/templates/Styleguide*</code>, and <code>/sitecore/definitions/components/GraphQL*</code></li>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/data/component-content/Styleguide</code></li>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/data/content/Styleguide</code></li>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/data/routes/styleguide</code> and <code>/data/routes/graphql</code></li>\r\n    <li>Delete <code>/data/dictionary/*.yml</code></li>\r\n  </ol>\r\n</div>\r\n"},"heading":{"value":"Welcome to Sitecore JSS"}}}]}}}}
```

When I try to look at this page via Experience editor I see "The remote name could not be resolved: 'rendering'". See the attached screenshot below. When I do this with ASP.NET it works perfectly fine.

[image: Rendering error]

While I was searching for the answer on my own, I have found an opened [issue](https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/issues/136) on official github repository of Sitecore Helix example with the similar issue, unfortunately, that's also didn't help.

What I could do to fix this?

Thanks for the info you could provide
(:

Comment: Please update your question title to be more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reason of this. I would debug it in following sequence considering different possibilities -

- Just check if your rendering container is running.
- If it it failing and you wish to debug its reason, uncomment environment variable *DEBUG=sitecore-jss:** , This will show you detailed logs which can be helpful to find out exact cause.

If container is up and running,

- Verify rendering hosts setting in CMS at path  */sitecore/system/Settings/Services/Rendering Hosts/Default*
- This should match with your rendering host settings

[image]

There are additional things to check in this detailed blog, please go through it - [Guide To Fix Setup Errors](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/troubleshooting-errors-for-sitecore-headless-sxa-next-js-xm-cloud-setup)

Hope this directs you to the fix :)